# Determine distribution fuction given density function of $(x, y)$

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

Given subspace $D^2 = \{{(x, y) \in \Bbb{R^2}: \begin{cases}x, y>0\\x+y<2 \end{cases}}\}$ and a density function:

$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{3}(x+y), (x,y) \in D^2\\0, (x,y) \notin D^2 \end{cases}$$

Determine a distribution function $F(x, y)$.

---

---

Okay, so the problem I encounter is how to correctly define lower and upper limits of integrals. We know that our subspace is an intersection of the following subspaces that form a triangle:

$$\begin{cases}
x > 0 \\
y > 0 \\
y < 2 - x
\end{cases}$$

If either $x$ or $y$ less than zero, $F(x, y) = 0$. We now need to define a cumulative formula inside this triangle using the following formula:

$$\frac{1}{3}\iint_{D^2}(x+y)dxdy = \frac{1}{3}\left(\int_{D^2}(x+y\middle |_{D^2})dx\right)$$

The lower limit of the first integral should be zero, the upper limit should be $x$, right? The lower limit of the second integral should also be zero while the upper one I am not sure at all. I understand that in the end both $x$ and $y$ should be present in a cumulative formula.

What is the preferred logic in this case to define them limits?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question $x$ and $y$ are fixed as the input of $F$, we introduce $u$ and $v$ variable to reprensent the horizontal and vertical axis separately.

\begin{align}
F(x,y) &= \int_0^x \int_0^y f(u,v) \, \, dvdu
\end{align}

If $x, y>0$ and $x+y<2$, the expression is simple as the region of interest is just a rectangle.

If $x \le 0$ or $y\le 0$, then $F(x,y)=0$.

If $x,y>0$ and $x+y>2$, we have an intersection of a rectangle with the domain (a triangle). The region outside the triangle has density $0$. Minimal function can be used to describe the intersect region compactly.

$$F(x,y) = \int_0^{\min(2,x)} \int_0^{\min(y,2-u)}f(u,v) \,\,dvdu$$

Comment: Why do $x, y > 0$ and $x + y < 2$ make a rectangle? It would be a rectangle if $ (x, y) \in [0, 2]$, for example.

Comment: consider if $(x,y)=(0.5,0.5)$, then the region of interest is just the rectangle $\{ 0 \leq u \leq 0.5, 0 \leq v \leq 0.5\}$ it is a rectangle that resides within the triangle.

Comment: Ok, really. Great, thank you.

Comment: It is fun, because we could have taken a real square and done the same computations. In the end, though, we could have divided the answer by two and obtain the same result. That was my inital approach.

Comment: Actually, no. It would not work like that.